Not able to select multiple submitted changelists under history tab in P4V
I am not able to select more than one submitted changelist under the history tab of P4V, neither with the help of shift + down key, nor with the help of ctrl key and mouse. It is occurring only under the history tab. In others tab like pending, submitted, etc., it is working perfectly fine. I've tried on different versions of perforce including the latest once, but nothing helped. Can anybody please advise?
I tried holding down the shift + up/down arrow keys and also tried holding ctrl key and selecting with the help of mouse one by one. It had always worked for me before. I was able to select multiple CLs under the history tab.
Thanks & Regards.
